# Display calculate total from the separate column

Tags: reporting-services, dynamics-crm, ssrs-2012

I work with CRM. Now I create some report from SSRS.

I need create some table like this:

[image: table example]

I can not create last column of the table. This column must contains sum of all rows previous column from groupping. How to do it? I work with crm online. Reports to CRM online can not use SQL - only fetch. And even I would can calculate value of this column from query I can not place it in last column - only second column because we are using grouping.

Comment: Have you tried creating that total column in Visual Studio ?

Comment: Maybe not. How to do it?

Comment: I inserted collumn inside group and calculated sum. But this collumn is second - not last. I need calculate it in last collumn.